# Don't know how to get description from OpenWeatherMap api, only the place and temperature

Tags: android, api

I've been working on making a simple weather app that displays the temperature, a description of the weather and the location. I'm able to get the location but can't figure out how to get the description of the weather from OpenWeatherMap and it's been bugging me for a few hours now. This is the part of the code in which I have this information laid out:

```
@Override
protected  void onPostExecute(String result){
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
        JSONObject weatherDatas = new JSONObject(jsonObject.getString("main"));



        double temperature = Double.parseDouble(weatherDatas.getString("temp"));

        int tempIn = (int) (temperature*1.8-459.67);

        String placeName = (String) jsonObject.get("name");


        MainActivity.tempeartureTextView.setText("" + tempIn);
        MainActivity.placeTextView.setText(placeName);
        Log.i("it made it", "to end of DownloadTask");
        //using http://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=94040,us&appid=b1b15e88fa797225412429c1c50c122a1  with zip code

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

But for the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the description.

The rest of the code is all here: MainActivity: http://pastebin.com/e2NtTSiP

DownloadTask: http://pastebin.com/ScEREz52

I followed a youtube tutorial on this so I don't quite understand everything but I kinda wanna just do it over and over again till I can get it right.

Answer (score 0):

if your JSON response is following :

```
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": -122.08,
    "lat": 37.39
  },
  "weather": [
    {
      "id": 500,
      "main": "Rain",
      "description": "light rain",
      "icon": "10n"
    }
  ],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 277.14,
    "pressure": 1025,
    "humidity": 86,
    "temp_min": 275.15,
    "temp_max": 279.15
  },
  "visibility": 16093,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 1.67,
    "deg": 53.0005
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 1
  },
  "dt": 1485788160,
  "sys": {
    "type": 1,
    "id": 471,
    "message": 0.0116,
    "country": "US",
    "sunrise": 1485789140,
    "sunset": 1485826300
  },
  "id": 5375480,
  "name": "Mountain View",
  "cod": 200
}
```

In order to get weather description from the response,

1. get "weather" array
2. for each JSON object present inside weather array, get the "description" property of the JSON object

   ```
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);
   JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("weather");
   for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                       JSONObject each = arr.get(i);
                       each.getString("description");
   }
   ```

Comment: Whenever I add this it just shows the default values that I put into the text views. Also, I was getting this error: https://gyazo.com/819739a0b7f46702ce3ac20639e49959   When I selected the top option it changed it to:                 JSONObject each = (JSONObject) arr.get(i);

Comment: Fixed the code. You must new create json object from response string.

Answer (score 0):

```
        String weatherInfo = jsonObject.getString("weather");

        Log.i("Weather content", weatherInfo);

        JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(weatherInfo);

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

            JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);

            String main = "";
            String description = "";

            main = jsonPart.getString("main");
            description = jsonPart.getString("description");

            MainActivity.descriptionTextView.setText(description);

        }
```

This fixed it for me!